# Melhorar visual de informações no Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chartjs, chart, usabilidade

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e utilizo o chart.js para gerar meus gráficos.
Porém, em nível de usabilidade, ele está ruim, pois não mostra todas as informações das colunas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olhando o gráfico acima aparentemente mostra que existe informações somente na coluna Total. Quando eu clico na legenda do total para remover a exibição dessa coluna, ele me mostra o resto das informações

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que gostaria que ele me mostrasse as informações sem ter que remover a coluna, porque as informações estão com valores próximos e não muito distante, tem algum jeito de eu fazer isso?

Demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvuguwfq/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar o `beginAtZero` na configuração de escalas no `yAxes`, na qual deixará explicito que a escala comece no zero.

```
 scales: {
    yAxes: [{ 
      ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
              },
              scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
              labelString: "Quantidade"
            }
       }],
```

Comment: Oi @valdeir-psr poderia me informar o porque do -1?

Comment: Obrigado @alessandra ! Deu certo!

Comment: @Alessandra_ E por que acredita que foi eu, somente eu ter formatado sua resposta? BTW: Não foi eu, apenas corrigir a formatação.